# UIPageControl not swiping

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I want to create a  custom `tableViewCell` with a `PageViewControl` on it. I want the user to be able to swipe on the cell to change the views. This is my code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    setupPageControl()
}

private func setupPageControl() {
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 7
    pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.orange
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
}
```

The problem is that the view does change only by tapping on it, and not swiping. The second problem is that the `pageControl` dots are in the middle of the screen and not on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: add this line self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

Comment: Have you tried setting the position of the UIPageControl?

Comment: use constraint  set position of the UIPageControl

Comment: @jcaron Yes I can put it on the button but it will be small and will not cover all the UIView, so it will not be able to detect the swipes I think

Comment: The page control is just the row of dots, it does not detect swipes.

Answer (score 1):

The page control does not detect swipes by itself. 
You can tap on the side to switch the page.

If you want to change with swipes you need to add a swipe gesture recongnizer to your cells
Or
Use a horizontal collection view with paging enabled. Then you can use delegates to connect the page control to the collection view, so that they can update each other